# Non-cliche Holiday Sounds for Comercial Campaign

Tags: holidays, cliche

What are some non-cliche "Holiday" sounds that could be used to decorate a series of commercial spots?

I don't always think of the Holidays as being strictly Christmas sounds, sleigh bells, carols etc.

What about other religions / areas of the world, what sounds do they associate with the Holiday season?

Are there sounds of Kwanzaa?
Or, Hanukkah?

Comment: What type of commercial? Radio or TV? If TV, what do you see on screen? Context would help give a better idea of what to advise on.

Comment: They will be for TV and internet, but I haven't seen them yet. I'm trying to gather as many ideas as possible though. 

Answer (score 2):

A very vivid sound memory of mine is the sound of a car driving down a gravel driveway, followed by footsteps, and the doorbell.  Obviously, I spent a lot of time waiting for family to show up.

Salvation Army bell-ringers, too... and there's a local homeless cellist that plays outside the malls during the holiday season, so I have his renditions of Christmas songs stuck in my head.

Comment: Ah the bell-ringers, forgot about them. Nice @Dave!

Answer (score 2):

I could envision a burp or a meow.  Depending on where you are, a car alarm or glass breaking.

Comment: I like the lateral thinking @Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Some free-associated sounds that I would tag for the holidays...

- excited children in the living room
- sharpening a carving knife
- cash registers
- busy crowds
- tire bys on slushy streets
- cold blustery winds
- fireplace crackles
- scissors shearing wrapping paper
- glasses clinking in toast
- intimate groups of celebratory tone
- large office parties with a little too much booze and honesty (that one's a little cliché, but still funny)

It's probably obvious that I come from a Xmas-celebrating home in a colder climate. Like Ryan said, knowing what you're selling or how you're selling it would help focus ideas.

EDIT: @Dave's salvation army ringer reminded me of the handbell choir I used to play in, we'd go around to people's parties or homes and perform carols. Pretty Xmassy, but another sound that triggers "holiday" for me.

Comment: Ahh, scissors on wrapping paper -- such a unique sound.

Comment: @Steve Urban I like the scissors cutting wrapping paper sound, also the sound of scotch tape peeling off the spool.

Comment: @Steve, man, you just got me nostalgic!

Comment: What about cookie sheets being slid into the oven?

Answer (score 1):

To me it's an English Brass Band. I grew up playing in them and it's the one part of Christmas I really miss in Ireland. My Dad has to ring me up at around 6am Christmas morning so I can hear the band wake the village up with the carol "Christians Awake".